# persistence.xml property values from properties file

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, properties, persistence.xml

I have below configuration for entityManger

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                     jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/AppDS"/>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory"
                     expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory"
                     jndi-name="java:comp/env/persistence/appPersistenceUnit"/>
```

I also have persistence.xml file, now I want to add hibernate-search feature to my application, so I have added below properties in my persistence.xml file ..

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/var/lucene/indexes" />
```

Here I want to externalize indexBase property value to properties file, something like this.

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="${index.location}" />
```

Can any please suggest how I can achieve this ?

I am using Spring version : 4.

Thanks.

**Update - 2**
I have added below code to my application-context.xml

Commented this

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory"
                         expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory"
                         jndi-name="java:comp/env/persistence/appPersistenceUnit"/>
```

and added below bean configuration ..

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/var/lucene/indexes</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

But after server restart it give below exception.. but if i keep same property in persistence.xml it works fine ..

```
Exception: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [vfs:/D:/App/Projects/Projects/wildfly/bin/content/app.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/appContext-web.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unabl
e to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-4.0.1.R
ELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELE
ASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEAS
E.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.
1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195) [spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEA
SE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:197) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]

        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.
3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.
3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]

        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.
Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.
jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) [spring-or
m-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) [spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.
RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-4.0.
1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) [spring-beans-4.0.1.R
ELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is
 not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level c
ache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
        at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildTimestampsRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:105) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache.<init>(UpdateTimestampsCache.java:73) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:72) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3
.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223) [hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
        ... 34 more

18:14:59,612 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./app: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [vfs:/
D:/Projects/wildfly/bin/content/app.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/appContext-web.xml]: Invocation of ini
t method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:86)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:71)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [vfs:/D:/Pro
jects/wildfly/bin/content/app.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/appContext-web.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exce
ption is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:197)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:272)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is
 not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level c
ache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
        at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildTimestampsRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:105)
        at org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache.<init>(UpdateTimestampsCache.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.<init>(CacheImpl.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
        ... 34 more
```

Also, i wanted to check what is the use of **configLocation** in LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ?

Thanks.

**Update - 3**

Sorry, I didn't provide full information, in my existing persistence.xml file
**hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache** was already set to true, and it was working fine.

But in next requirement I had to implement search feature, so I used hibernate-search. And I have added **hibernate.search.default.indexBase** and **hibernate.search.default.directory_provider** in persistence.xml, after that it's working fine. It created index when entity is checked in, also updates index when entity is updated..

As I have to deploy this code on different environment, i have to specify different location for each environment. For all environments i have different properties files. So i want to do same for this **hibernate.search.default.indexBase** as well.. but after adding implementation as you suggested, still its not working ..

let me know if I can help you with any other information to find out solution ...

**Update - 4**

Below is my `persistence.xml` file ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="appPersistenceUnit"
                      transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/AppDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.app.domain.User</class>
        <!-- Other entity classes -->
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>

            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
                      value="persistence-units/appPersistenceUnit"/>

            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform"
                      value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>

            <!-- Disable transaction auto commit (production) -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>

            <!-- Default character set -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>

            <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class"
                      value="jta"/>

            <!-- SQL dialect -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

            <!-- Naming strategy -->
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>

            <!-- Format SQL outpout -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>

            <!-- Enabling Statistics -->
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>

            <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update"
                to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create"
                but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes
                to the database -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>

            <!-- Enable batch procession using an integer between 10-50 -->
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="40"/>

            <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>

            <!-- Envers -->
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy"
                      value="org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy"/>
            <property
                    name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_end_rev_field_name"
                    value="revision_end"/>
            <property
                    name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp"
                    value="true"/>
            <property
                    name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_revend_timestamp_field_name"
                    value="revision_end_time"/>
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix" value="_aud"/>
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name" value="revision"/>
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name" value="revision_type"/>
            <property name="org.hibernate.envers.revision_listener"
                      value="com.app.listener.revision.RevisionListenerImpl"/>

            <!-- Infinispan -->
            <!-- Enables the query cache. You still need to set individual queries
                to be cacheable. Call org.hibernate.Query.setCacheable(true) to initiate. -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            <!-- Enable second level cache. Requires session flushing. -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>

            <!-- Hibernate Search properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/var/lucene/indexes" />


        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and, below is my spring configuration file, also i have added `<bean>` configuration which i tried after your inputs, which is commented below `jee:jndi-lookup`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd">

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                     jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/AppDS"/>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory"
                     expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory"
                     jndi-name="java:comp/env/persistence/appPersistenceUnit"/>

    <!-------------------------

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/var/lucene/indexes</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="entityManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="exceptionTranslator"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

Let me know if you want me to add any other details . .

Thanks ..

Comment: Not sure why Hibernate thinks 2nd level cache is being used; do add `<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>` in your config to proceed. Will update once I have figured out the reason.

Comment: please check my update-3 added in my original question.. Thanks.

Comment: please post complete `persistence.xml` and all framework versions

Answer (score 1):

Since the `persistence.xml` lies outside the spring it isn't possible to inject properties via spring property placeholder.

The inherited method [`setJpaProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setJpaProperties-java.util.Properties-) of Springs' [`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) will solve the purpose you are looking forward too.

Sample spring bean configuration would look something like below -

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">${index.location}</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
```

Note that this will still read the configuration from `persistence.xml` with additional facilities. (*e.g. customized location for `persistence.xml` instead of default `META-INF`*)

Comment: please check my update-2 in original question, i have added configuration as you suggested, but it didn't work for me...